# After Uploading the Project on localHost with Publish Folder I am Getting Sql Error - The specified LocalDB instance does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.
)

[image: My Sql Name]

[image: The Sql Connection String]

P.s I Also have tried putting Server Name With Connection String:-
1 `<add connectionString="Server=Rushabh\LOCALDB#628F4E4B;Database=JainNamkin;User ID=sa;Password=demo123" name="Local" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`
2 `<add connectionString="Server=(localdb)\Local;Database=JainNamkin;User ID=sa;Password=demo123" name="Local" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`
Putting those 2 still gave the same error

[image: Server Name]

Comment: Update I Solve IT The Error Was Simple I didnt Configure the Sql Server so it was throwing a error